# How do I obtain the Natal SDK?

Tags: sdk, xbox

How do I obtain the Natal SDK? Where to take it from (google had not given me lot of help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Microsoft have released the SDK to a limited number of games studios but it is not freely available.  You might be able to find a pirate copy on a torrent site if that sort of thing doesn't bother you.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a third-party (open-source?) SDK available from [Code Laboratories](http://codelaboratories.com/kb/nui).  The NUI SDK is still under development, but you can download it and start using it.

Answer (score 1):

well, I've looked around, and I can't find it (legal or otherwise).
The natal kinect SDK would be great fun to play with... come on microsoft and xbox!